# Joining 3 tables in sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I know this is pretty simple but i'm sql novice and don't have a clue how to write this query. I have 3 tables: rekon, flows and notes.

rekon:

```
no    sex
a     F
b     F
c     M
d     F
e     M
```

flows:

```
 no   notes_no
 a    PX
 a    SX
 a    
 a    DX
 b    MX
 b    CX
 c    
 c    PX
 d    LX
 d    WX
```

notes:

```
 notes_no  no  
 AX        a
 BX        f
 CX        g
 DX        a
 EX        c 
 FX        c
 GX        g
 HX        b
 PX        a
 SX        a
```

I want to list all entries from notes that are not part of flows and only for clients from rekon that are women. So the result should be

```
no   sex   notes_no
a    F     AX
b    F     HX
```

I tried using statement

```
notes.notes_no not in (select distinct notes_no from flows)
```

but I have to many rows and oracle has problems calculating it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So where the real prob. is??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT notes.* FROM notes
INNER JOIN rekon ON rekon.no = notes.no
LEFT JOIN flows ON flows.no = notes.no
WHERE flows.no IS NULL and sex = 'F'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select N.*
from rekon R
    join notes N
        on N.no = R.no
where R.sex = 'F'
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from flows F
        where F.notes_no = N.notes_no
    )
;
```

The query might be slightly different based on the definitions of your inter-table referential relationships, so the `exists` predicate may as well read

```
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from flows F
        where F.no = N.no
            and F.notes_no = N.notes_no
    )
```

If your Oracle has problems querying the data in a reasonable time, then you might

1. be lacking statistics computed on your tables (... so Oracle picks a wrong execution plan)
2. be having badly organized tables (... so Oracle does unnecessary amount of useless work)
3. be having a badly configured Oracle server (... so it struggles during hash joins)
4. be having a too slow server marchine